Refresh staging database from production
What are the common approaches these days for refreshing a lower environment (staging NoSQL database) from production, other than writing my own ETL script ? Production changes often and there could be random schema drifts, so thinking about a daily refresh. What concerns or best practices should we keep in mind?
With our own scripts, we think it'll be messy and slow as the database is large (100GB).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
